# SQL Sub Query to resolve table references until all references are exhausted

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I will preface this by saying I am self taught with SQL and usually can find what I need in a quick search. I haven't been able to figure this one out.

I am working with a db that contains Drawings, Assemblies and Part Files. The assemblies can have several sub assemblies, with more sub assemblies.

I am looking for a query where I can define the top level filename and return all files beneath it, then search on the sub assemblies file type (asm), using these ReferenceDocID's as TopDocID's for the next level of search.

I am using a single table for all the information and the columns are as shown.

| TopDocID | Filename | ReferenceDocID | Reference Filename |

Any help is appreciated.

Chuck

Comment: Have you looked into creating a recursive CTE (Common Table Expression).  This works in SQL Server (not sure about other RDBMs).  Could you also edit your question with the appropriate tag for the Database system you're using?  I ask this because if you're not using SQL Server my suggestion may not apply, but others may be able to help.

Comment: I have not. Never used it, but I will look into it and yes I am using SQL server. Thanks

Comment: You should also supply some example output, so we can see what you need. Maybe just a group by? Good luck Chuck!